# Минусы использования Canvas (HTML5)

Tags: canvas, html

Собираюсь использовать в своём приложении Canvas HTML5. Но большую часть можно было бы реализовать и с помощью обычного HTML+CSS. Есть два варианта:

1. Использовать Canvas только в случае крайней необходимости, а в остальном HTML+CSS
2. Использовать Canvas везде, где только можно (для реализации проще)

Поэтому хотелось бы узнать, какие ОТРИЦАТЕЛЬНЫЕ моменты в использовании Canvas? И какой из вариантов выбрали бы вы?

Comment: Мой совет - использовать то что легче.
Тень например делать на canvas, а рамку на css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CANVAS имеет особенность - производительно его элементов скорость обработки и т.д. и т.п. зависит напрямую от возможностей браузера и компьютера. Например, [вот](http://www.smashcat.org/av/canvas_test/), я на своем опыте наглядно убедился как **опера** давала по производительности **26-36** fps, **firefox 4** давал без проблем **>150**. При том у меня высокопроизводительная конфигурация компьютера с широкополосным доступом. Вот как это будет выглядеть в нетбуке на winxp со не очень новыми версиями браузеров я не представляю. Выбор за вами.

Answer (score 2):

Использование canvas - проще и быстрее. А если в старых браузерах нет поддержки, то возможно как сделать надпись об этом, или загрузить обычную картинку в самом теге.

Comment: Нужно подчеркнуть, что в браузерах с поддержкой canvas он и будет отображен. А там ,где поддержки нет- будет отображено альтернативное содержимое. Подробнее тут: https://domhtml.ru/tag-html-canvas/

Comment: SVG тоже не сильно тяжело использовать

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 еще не во всех браузерах поддерживается так что пользуйтесь старым методом
я советую выбрать 1

Comment: Тут еще такой момент, что определенную часть так или иначе придется писать с помощью Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Собственно с технической точки зрения Canvas нужен для отрисовки растровой графики (2D, 3D) и в этом он очень удобен.

Единственный существенный минус - это отсутствие поддержки в версиях IE младше 9-ой. Поэтому если ожидаемая аудитория приложения в своем большинстве использует IE 6, 7, 8 (например, сотрудники корпораций), то Canvas HTML5 лучше не брать (хотя и в этом случае есть заплатка в виде Chrome Frame), а если большинство использует Firefox, Chrome, Opera, то Canvas HTML5 очень даже не плох.

Время разработчика (Ваше) - это ценный ресурс, поэтому если, используя HTML5 Canvas, на нем можно сэкономить, то лучше так и сделать.